# What is the proper name for this filter?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, filter

What is the proper name for this filter for photos that appeared in the opener of Netflix's *Narcos*? Any tips on how to recreate this filter either in an app or Photoshop.

[image]

http://www.artofthetitle.com/title/narcos/

Comment: I think this should be in the Photography stack tbh. 
I'm not sure it would have a name anyway, its appears to be a blend of a  B&W photo and a negative image of a document, with a pink tint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could possibly be a **Cross Processing Effect.**

> This is the result of developing color print or slide film in the
>   wrong chemical. The effect is great especially that the colors look
>   different. The image has a unique wild color and various contrasts.
>   The picture looks great although the real color of the image is
>   manipulated.

You can read more here:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_processing
- http://naldzgraphics.net/photography/photo-effects-in-photography/